# boto3 DMS delete DMS task logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-dms

I am writing scripts in Python that are deleting DMS tasks using the boto3 package. I wonder if there is any way of programmatically deleting CloudWatch logging for the tasks? I can't find any option to do this with the describe_replication_instance_task_logs function.

Comment: Figure out what the log group for these kind of logs is, figure out what the name of the logstream is for a given dms task and then talk to cloudwatch to delete the logstream(s).

Comment: Both Cloudwatch logs and DMS logs are different right. I would want to delete the DMS logs stored in the DMS replication instance.

Comment: If Cloudwatch log is the concern I would be doing this with cloud watch retention policy of 15 days